# Does emacs support multiple macros in a same buffer just as vim?

Tags: emacs, macros

I'm new in emacs. I know you can use <kbd>C-x (</kbd> to start recording a macro. Use <kbd>C-x )</kbd> to stop recording and use <kbd>C-x e</kbd> or <kbd>F4</kbd> to play it. However, I didn't find a way to record multiple macros in the same buffer. I want to know whether emacs support this feature?

Comment: `C-h r`, then `i keyboard macro RET`. (You should probably learn `C-h r` and `i` before learning keys like `C-x (`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs maintains a keyboard macro ring, which stores all the defined macros. You can cycle through the ring by

- `C-x C-k C-n` next macro (`kmacro-cycle-ring-next`)
- `C-x C-k C-p` previous macro (`kmacro-cycle-ring-previous`)

You can see which macro will be used in your mini-buffer.

Perhaps you want to read this manual: 
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macro-Ring.html#Keyboard-Macro-Ring

Comment: Ogrish Man: You can also bind a macro to a key sequence; or *name* it and then call it by name (via `M-x`). You can even store the definitions permanently in your init file. Again, see the manual for details on all aspects.